# Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/ezSearch.cshtml)

Tags: umbraco

I am having some issue with ezSearch (Umbraco) and it is very similar to this one

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ezsearch/bugs-feedback-suggestions/48460-Search-error-when-searching-for-test-keyword?p=0#comment176864
Here is the screenshot of error

http://our.umbraco.org/media/upload/e08b702e-b738-42a4-81d8-382a4400b96a/error.jpg

Can anyone hep me with this please?

Thank you,
Adi

Comment: Any suggestion? BR, Adi

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ezSearch, and from reading the ezSearch.cshtml this looks like a bug if the query passed to the macro is " ". That is to say, if the search is empty, it works ok, but if the search is an actual quoted space then the line in the cshtml: (line 60 in my version)

```
// Check the search term isn't empty
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.SearchTerm))
{
    // Tokenize the search term
    model.SearchTerms = Tokenize(model.SearchTerm);
...
etc.
...
}
```

ends up with a bad set of tokens in model.SearchTerms.

it's a bit of a hack, but i think putting this *before* that **if** statement will help.

```
model.SearchTerm = model.SearchTerm.Replace("\"","").Replace(" ","").Replace("'","");
```

..hope that helps.

'ingie.